# rxjs 'merge' operator not working with toPromise()?

Tags: promise, rxjs

I have the following code:

```
const observable_one = this.loadFromStorage(key)   //fast!
const observable_two = this.http.myRequest()       //slow!

my_observable = 
    merge(
      observable_one,
      oobservable_two
    )
```

Now, when I do the following, it does only give data AFTER the slow second one has finished

```
const data = await my_observable.toPromise()
```

whilst

```
my_observable.subscribe(data  => {
    //work with data
})
```

emits twice, as expected.

How can this be explained? How can toPromise() know there is something coming up?

For some reasons I prefer the await / toPromise() approach.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `combineLatest`

```
combineLatest(observable_one,oobservable_two).subscribe(data  => {
    //work with data
})
```

Comment: But this needs both observables to emit data first, right?

Comment: yes, you are right! this way you can sync data from both sources and then perform any task on it. I will say don't use `toPromise`. because it's non-cancelable if you move to some other screen and it's eager in nature. on the other hand, observable behave like lazy never invoked until you subscribe and cancelable anytime.